# How Ruby On Rails can be combined with Erlang?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erlang, cowboy

I have the "Wappalyzer" extension installed in my browser. And several times I saw some webapps which were built with RubyOnRails and Erlang, on the Cowboy server.

So, could you tell me how these technologies can be combined in one project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RubyOnRails as with all frameworks can call out tertiary processes on the server either directly through:  ` <command> `

or indirectly though ActiveJob (or some background task alternative)

Erlang/Beam/OTP, etc.. can be leveraged though this mechanism

Answer (score 1):

Cowboy got support for [FastCGI](https://www.google.fr/url?url=https://github.com/extend/cowboy_fcgi&rct=j&frm=1&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ei=xkdCVcmLOcSuU_yVhNAD&ved=0CBQQFjAA&sig2=yitnAG3fRVcj6qSfFBkL7w&usg=AFQjCNFaMW_VV0-cf7CT8Ii4KOp-_P8vGA) and RoR can be run using FastCGI.
I don't know if that's what people do, but it's one way to do it.